Spotlight Keeps Forgetting the System Drive
I've recently upgraded to macOS Sonoma, and while sometimes when I search for the name of an app in Spotlight it returns it immediately (so I can just hit enter to open it), sometimes it behaves as if it's completely unaware of what apps I have installed.
It seems very much as if Spotlight keeps "forgetting" its indexes and having to rebuild them, as I sometimes see the indexing bar on the Spotlight UI, while it's indexing I can search my apps successfully.
I've already tried running mdutil -E on some volumes to force it to rebuild indexes, but I usually only get back the message "Spotlight server is disabled" which seems strange, as while I'm not getting all of the results I expect, I am getting results back (typically limited to files in my local accounts) so it's not completely inactive.
While Spotlight was a lot slower for me under Catalina, I never had any issue like this.
Update: This issue gets stranger and stranger, it seems that while Spotlight is failing to return expected results, it doesn't even recognise that it has an index on the affected volume, so my output might look something like:
mdutil -as:
/:
    No index
/System/Volumes/Data:
    No index.
/System/Volumes/Preboot:
    No index.
/Volumes/Backup:
    No index

However once re-indexing kicks in again it shows as normal (Indexing enabled) until it decides it doesn't see anything anymore.
But the weirdest part is I can still run some searches despite having "no index", and mdfind doesn't return any errors (though it has the same limits as the Spotlight UI).

Please clarify what you mean by “files in my local accounts.” What exactly is, and is not, being indexed?

I had a similar problem, it seems that Spotlight was finding content and apps on my TimeMachine drive instead of my main drive. I left the TM drive always connected. I found that disconnecting the TimeMachine drive returned Spotlight to expected behavior.

@LincD. I mean Spotlight finds items in my user account(s) but not the system volume as a whole, i.e- it can see applications under ~/Applications but not under /Applications.

Please enter this command: sudo mdutil -a -i off and then this one: sudo mdutil -a -i on. If you get an error message from either one, post it. Otherwise, wait a few minutes for the indexes to build, then test.
